SearchKit filter for user contacts
I want to filter all user contacts in a SearchKit table to only have real external contacts in that table. I am using the CMS-ID field for this as described here: CMS User Query with SearchKit.
Unfortunately the query only returns results when I am working as Drupal admin user. It seems that there is a permission missing for the regular user. Using the CMS-ID field on the extended search as a regulat user works though.
Any ideas on that? Is this the proper way to filter user contacts?

you can bypass the permission on a display, by clicking on Bypass permission.


Thank you, that works. It is more of a workaround to me though. I wonder what excact permission is missing and why the regular user gets results doing the same search with the extended search.
